# cypher query to visualize existent relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am just trying to use cypher query to visualize an existent relationship but continuously have an "error" message. Can someone take a look and check my query?

Here's my query

```
MATCH (n:ns3__Object)-[r:ns4__P102_has_title]->(n:ns4__E35_Title)
   RETURN n:ns3__Object,r,n:ns4__E35_Title LIMIT 25
```

Error output:

[image: Error output]

Existent Relationship:

[image: Existent Relationship]

Comment: It's better if you can enter your query here.

Comment: My query is -> "MATCH (n:ns3__Object)-[r:ns4__P102_has_title]->(n:ns4__E35_Title) RETURN n:ns3__Object,r,n:ns4__E35_Title LIMIT 25"

Comment: can you post some sample data so that we can try it out on it and give you a reply. ie. all the create statements of a sample graph.

Comment: It seems I have simply solved it when I removed "n" before ":". I will inform you about the sample data later since it does not belong to me! thank you for your response. best...